# Spring.net + Nhibernate Integration Tests Pass When They Should Not

Tags: nhibernate, integration-testing, spring.net

I'm using Spring.net with NHiberante (HibernateTemplate) to implement my DAO's.

I also have some integration tests, that extend from 'AbstractTransactionalDbProviderSpringContextTests '.

DI is working fine, and all test pass BUT sometimes they pass **even when they shouldn't**.

For example if my hbm.xml files have an error like this:

`<class name="Confluence.Domain.User" table="THIS TABLE DOES NOT EXIST">`

The tests fails, but if the error is like this one:

`<many-to-many
 class="Confluence.Domain.User"
 column="THIS COLUMN DOES NOT EXIST"/>`

the tests pass silently hiding the bug.

I'm testing it using SetComplete() and checking the DB for the changes, but I think the whole idea of this kind of tests is not to do so.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much!

@Ben: If I have to actually execute the SQL scripts to see if they work, what is the benefit of using this kind of Spring tests?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Spring Tests.

I'm not a spring user (I prefer Castle Windsor) and I generally leave it _out_ of my tests.  Perhaps you can ask a new question here that is more directed at that topic.

Comment: By Spring tests I mean Spring.Test.NUnit. AbstractTransactionalDbProviderSpringContextTests that is a convenience abstract class, so each method annotated with [test] runs inside a transaction that is always rolled back, so the DB doesn't get polluted by test, and I don't have to cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a syntax error in your mapping, then NHibernate will fail on config.BuildSessionFactory()

But for mispelled/non-existence database objects, the only way for NHibernate to know is to actually run a query...  So you might employ some integration tests to test insert/select on a single entity, to make sure it works.

Not sure what this has to do with Spring.NET though.

Answer (score 2):

When testing your NH based DAO's you should flush the session so that the database is updated with the new information but still rollback as before.  How to do this is explained here - http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5246  I've added this to the reference docs.  Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Mark